# ViewPager Disable Swiping

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have a `ViewPager` which has 3 fragments. Fragment A on the left, B in the middle and C on the right. Fragment C has a `ListView` which fills the whole width of the screen. I implemented a swipe listener on my ListView items using the following code:

SWIPE DETECTOR :

```
public class SwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

public static enum Action {
    LR, // Left to Right
    RL, // Right to Left
    TB, // Top to bottom
    BT, // Bottom to Top
    None // when no action was detected
}



private static final String logTag = "SwipeDetector";
private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
private static final int VERTICAL_MIN_DISTANCE = 80;
private static final int HORIZONTAL_MIN_DISTANCE = 80;
private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
private Action mSwipeDetected = Action.None;

public boolean swipeDetected() {
    return mSwipeDetected != Action.None;
}

public Action getAction() {
    return mSwipeDetected;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downX = event.getX();
            downY = event.getY();
            mSwipeDetected = Action.None;
            return false; // allow other events like Click to be processed
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            upX = event.getX();
            upY = event.getY();

            float deltaX = downX - upX;
            float deltaY = downY - upY;

            // horizontal swipe detection
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > HORIZONTAL_MIN_DISTANCE) {
                // left or right
                if (deltaX < 0) {
                   // Log.i(logTag, "Swipe Left to Right");
                    mSwipeDetected = Action.LR;
                    return true;
                }
                if (deltaX > 0) {
                   // Log.i(logTag, "Swipe Right to Left");
                    mSwipeDetected = Action.RL;
                    return true;
                }
            } else

                // vertical swipe detection
                if (Math.abs(deltaY) > VERTICAL_MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // top or down
                    if (deltaY < 0) {
                        Log.i(logTag, "Swipe Top to Bottom");
                        mSwipeDetected = Action.TB;
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (deltaY > 0) {
                        Log.i(logTag, "Swipe Bottom to Top");
                        mSwipeDetected = Action.BT;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}}
```

I use it in the following way :

```
        listView.setOnTouchListener(swipeDetector);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                final int position, long id) {
            Log.d("CLICKED", "CLICKED");
            if (swipeDetector.swipeDetected()) {
                Log.d("SWIPING", "SWIPING");
                Log.d("ACTION", swipeDetector.getAction().toString());
                final Button del = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
                if (swipeDetector.getAction() == SwipeDetector.Action.LR) {
                    Log.d("LEFT TO RIGHT", "Left to right");
```

This works perfectly fine with Activities. However, the problem now is that when I swipe, it assumes I am swiping in the ViewPager and takes me back to the middle fragment. Is there a way to disable the ViewPager swiping on this ListView or change the focus so that this works?